# Flutter: Provider shows Exception but app run fine while using default listen:true

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm Using provider in `initState()` to call the api but if I use `listen:false` then it does not update UI and it always shows me loader but if I use `listen:true` then app works fine but in the terminal it shows me `exception` and tells me write `listen:false`.

My UI,

```
class ChopperNewsCard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChopperNewsCardState createState() => _ChopperNewsCardState();
}

class _ChopperNewsCardState extends State<ChopperNewsCard> {
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  int currentPage = 5;
  ChopperApiStore _apiStore = ChopperApiStore();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      _apiStore = Provider.of<ChopperApiStore>(context,);//<--- here it tells me to write listen:false
    });
    _apiStore.getResponse(currentPage);
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.pixels ==
          scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        if (currentPage < 20) {
          currentPage = currentPage + 5;
          _apiStore.getResponse(currentPage);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Observer(builder: (context) {
      return Container(
        height: height * 0.37,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: _apiStore.res.articles == null
            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
            : ListView.builder(...),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

api calling class,

```
class ChopperApiStore extends _ChopperApiStore with _$ChopperApiStore{}

abstract class _ChopperApiStore with Store{
  ApiCall apiCall = ApiCall();
  @observable
  ChopperNews res = ChopperNews();

  @action
  Future<void> getResponse(int page) async {
     var data = await apiCall.getNews(page);
     res = data;
  }
}
```

the error I'm getting,

```
======== Exception caught by scheduler library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree.

This is likely caused by an event handler (like a button's onPressed) that called
Provider.of without passing `listen: false`.

To fix, write:
Provider.of<ChopperApiStore>(context, listen: false);

It is unsupported because may pointlessly rebuild the widget associated to the
event handler, when the widget tree doesn't care about the value.

The context used was: ChopperNewsCard(dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _ChopperNewsCardState#8f6cd)
'package:provider/src/provider.dart':
Failed assertion: line 262 pos 7: 'context.owner.debugBuilding ||
          listen == false ||
          debugIsInInheritedProviderUpdate'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:262:7)
#3      _ChopperNewsCardState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:fruitley/week-5/bonus/chopper/widgets/chopper_news_card.dart:32:28)
#4      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1117:15)
#5      SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1063:9)
#6      SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:971:5)
...
```

Comment: you have to write listen false in initstate because every time notifyListner calls it will also invoke initState provider because you didn't write listen false in initState

Comment: @HamzaSiddiqui yes but if I write then it does not update the UI and shows loading forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I'm dumb. I didn't even need to use `addPostFrameCallback`.
I just removed it and if I want to use provider outside of widget tree that I must use `listen:false` as it was showing in the exception so now everything makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to use `listen:true` to have the `build` method called you are suppose to override `didChangeDependencies` rather then `initState` Checkout this article it might help https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-provider-and-didchangedependencies-15678f502262

Comment: I just noticed that you are using `addPostFrameCallback` In this case it might not be such a good option because the function will be invoked with every change. Maybe you need to change your logic and use `FutureBuilder` or `FutureProvider` instead. I would look into that.

Comment: I tried using `didChangeDependencies` but it still gives me the same exception and if user scrolls to the end then it should show more results now how I can do that with `futurebuilder` I don't know that so that's why I'm doing

Comment: Have you considered using a package for infinite scroll? [pull_to_refresh](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh) is a pretty good option.  If you can't then you must change your logic. You need to make it so that the call to `addPostFrameCallback` is inside your `build` method

Comment: it is an internship so I need to do everything from scratch without any packages so I think changing my logic is the only option. thank you for everything

Comment: Very nice, good luck with your internship